# .hgignore for VB6 project

Tags: vb6, mercurial

I need to pull a VB6 project into mercurial.  It is not currently source-controlled.  I'm good with mercurial, but less familiar with VB6.  Need a good start for an .hgignore.

For VB devs reading that are not familiar with Mercurial, mainly I need to know what file types are authored code or are only changed by user action, and which are generated by the environment or by compilation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only user file generated by Visual Studio 6 for VB6 that I know of is the `.vbw` file.

From [Beginners Tutorial To the VB6 IDE](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/beginners-tutorial-vb6-ide):

> A .vbw file (VB workspace file) contains information about where you left the position of each window in your project the last time you worked on it in the IDE (this is not an essential file – if it's missing, VB will use defaults to position the windows when you load your project).

That's the only file (extension) that I ignore for Subversion.

Comment: Thanks, can I ignore the whole `exe/` directory, or is there anything in there that should be included?

Comment: There is no exe directory--unlike modern Visual Studio, there is no bin/lib folder--you build the exe wherever you want. So, if you are building in the project folder, exclude the exe. If you are building in a subfolder of the project folder, exclude the folder.